# UNIONing dynamic list of tables in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have more than 100 tables in Redshift that I'd like to UNION to create one consolidated table. I can't hardcode this query because the list of tables will grow quite quickly. So I want to be able to achieve a process wherein I'm able to write something like, "UNION all tables where the table name contains 'orders'".

What's the best way to do this in Redshift? I'm open to using third party tools/languages to do this if needed, but if possible to do within Redshift, that would be ideal.

Comment: "The list of tables will grow quite quickly".  Something is wrong with your data model.  You should be putting all the data in a single table -- or at the very least adding a new view every time a new table is added.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's a use case where each table has data from a different client (and is authorized separately)

Comment: . . Then you should have a step that loads the data into a single table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's not a manual script that's doing this. It's a third party tool that's creating separate tables, so we don't have direct control over that. And that's basically my question here - how do we now get data from all these tables into a single table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done inside of Redshift - I'll let someone with a bright idea chime in but I don't think there is a way.

So you will need an external system to compose the query for you.  The table names can be found in the Redshift catalogs and composing the query can be made in a templating system like jinja2.  Jinja2 can loop on a list of tables and build the UNION ALL SQL for you and runs stand alone or as a python library.  Or you can have a process (Lambda) that builds a view over all your tables and you query just accesses the view.

Now let's talk about why you shouldn't be doing this.  First off Redshift is designed to be efficient on large tables.  The storage block size is 1MB and for tables of less than a few million rows can be significantly inefficient.  A table of 10,000 rows can use less than 1% of the storage space for actual data so reading these tables can have a high overhead and if you need to scan 100's of these you can spend all your time reading barely used blocks.  Not only is this inefficient in terms of execution but also in disk storage.  You could be heading for big problems on this path.

Also, the Redshift query compiler has limits on segments and parts in the query.  Unioning all these tables will hit these limits and fail as you move forward and add tables.  Defining a process that will break one day is not likely where you want to be.